# forkJoin undefined when share component (and combining boolean variables)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service used in many components and I need to share the result of a forkjoin, but the component is coming as undefined

*My service logic layer*

```
         @Injectable({
                providedIn: 'root'
            })
            
            export class CoreStateService {
                private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
                hasError$: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable();

                constructor(private api: HomeGuardService) {}
                
                    public verifyFailed(): Observable<any>{
                    return forkJoin([this.api.getPerfilNew$, this.api.getPosicaoConsolidada()])
                         .pipe(
                            catchError(err => {
                                this.statusError = err.status;
                                console.log('--->', this.statusError);
                                return of([]); 
                            }),
                            map(([perfilInvestors, position]) => {
                                this.perfilInvestors = perfilInvestors;
                                this.investments = position;
                                //verify if perfil failed
                                if (this.statusError) {
                                    this.perfilFailed = true
                                } else {
                                    this.perfilFailed = false
                                }
                                //verify if  investments failed
                                if (this.investments) {
                                    this.hasInvestiments = true;
                                }
                                //combine investments and statusError
                                this.hasError$ = combineLatest([this.statusError, this.hasInvestiments])
                                    .pipe(
                                        map(([statusError, hasInvestiments]) => statusError && !hasInvestiments)
                                    );
                            }),
                            tap(hasError$ => this.subject.next(hasError$)),
                        );
                }
    }
```

*In my component:*

```
   constructor(private coreState: CoreStateService) {}
    
public ngOnInit() {
        this.coreState.subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    }
```

Result in console:
[image]

**I Need to return to components if hasError$ is true or false.**

Comment: There is return statement in the constructor, but you will get a class instance on the initialisation instead of the returned value in constructor.

Comment: There is a `map` in the stream's pipe, but nothing is returned. Probably `tap` is what should be used, but the logic is complicated. So I am not sure what is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to subscribe on hasError$ instead to subscribe the whole service:

```
this.coreState.hasError$.subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
```

2- Is there any calling to `verifyFailed()` in any place? because it needs to be called to produce the results.